# Zen Pinball 2 PSVita, tick button?

Tags: ps-vita, zen-pinball-2

I downloaded the Plants Vs Zombies table for Zen Pinball 2 on the PSVita and I think it's great fun (if a bit easy!).  Does anyone know what the round button with a tick on it signifies that pops up on the right hand side of the screen intermittently?  I've tried pressing it but it just operates the right flipper.  Sorry if I'm being thick and there's a perfectly simple explanation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It activates plants you have accumulated (I.e. pepper, cherry bomb) to use at your discretion instead of automatically activating. I'm not positive how many work this way but so far this is what I've found.